# Get the opened port when using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Can I get the port number when I am connecting to remote using `NSURLConnection`, let say the remote port is`HTTP(80)`, how do I know my local port pair?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Netstat information is not accessible in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but the only command that will help you is "lsof -i" which will sometimes show you the applications and the tcp ports they use.